# How to connect tigase to openfire?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, tigase

I have two `Xmpp server`,one is `tigase`, another is `openfire`. Now i want users can `communicated` with each other between the two servers, how can i do? how can i modify the configuration of the `tigase`?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do anything to the configuration. Assuming DNS is setup correctly for domains on both servers, they should use automatically and by default s2s to connect to each other and communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to enable s2s service in both Tigase and Openfire .